# iq-test.net question - shaded squares on strips

Tags: pattern, visual

This question makes absolutely no sense to me and it is driving me crazy that I cannot find a solution.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's

> green, blank, blank.

because...

calling the cells  A,B,C,D,E,F
 and examples 1,2,3,4,5

1-2 deonstrates that B is the opposite of D

It can also be deduced  by looking at 1,2,3,4,5 that A,B,C are not correlated with each other

then it can be seen that A always matches F and C always matces E

leaving only one of the patterns offered as the answer.

3 and 4 identical hints that there is no vertical sequence

5 being half filled suggests that the D,E,F are can be determined by A,B,C

it took me a lot longer to deduce this than the time I allow to answer most IQ test questions.

Comment: I agree, but this doesn't explain why they chose to make 3 and 4 identical.

Comment: @AmitNaidu yes it does, it goes to show that there isn't a change from row to row (unless something really odd is happening).  Its a bit of a hint in that sense, not to look for an operation on the entire row to the next, but something they all share in common.

Answer (score 2):

Extracting a pattern from so little data will always be ambiguous.

My guess would be

> Green, blank, blank

because if we assume there is an independent operation for deducing the fifth element in a column from the other four, we have existing samples for the fifth and sixth column, and only one answer choice that fits both.

Answer (score 1):

> I notice that there are 3 shaded (blue) blocks and 3 non-shaded blocks per row.
> From this alone, I can tell that the likely solution is(final row):
> u = un-shaded, s = shaded
> **Given**: u, u, u;
> **Solved**: s, s, s;
> **Final**: u, u, u, s, s, s

**[INCORRECT]**

Comment: I just noticed that the blocks on the right are the choices, oof.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE. Please hide your answers in spoilers.

Comment: I used ">!" before everything, didn't seem too work.

Comment: Actually, that was my presumed answer at first haha

Answer (score 1):

If we treat the blocks as pixels which move on a small screen, and roll over from one side to the other, as they go off the edge of the screen, then we get the answer:

> blank,green,green

as we can see fairly quickly that the two pixels on the left each move left one space to the left, and then wrap around to the right, and the pixel on the left moves 0, then 1, then 2, then 3 spaces. Not sure if this is how to interpret this question (I have noticed some IQ questions are just poorly designed), but This is at least a logically consistant answer